# How to publish multiple live streams on FMS with the same metadata?

Tags: actionscript-3, streaming, flash-builder, flash-media-server

Is it possible to publish several live streams on flash media server with the same controlling metadata? I.e. two different clients are connecting to the same URL, using the same stream name and etc, but publishing different streams?

Is there some else metadata except URL and stream name, allowing to distinguish two streams?

I have tried to publish two streams with the same names and second have failed.

I know I can use dynamically generated stream name to publish. But can I avoid using this method?

Answer (score 0):

For Publishing:

you can use the different name of stream for publishing for every netstream object. Stream name is a unique for the live publishing. if already stream is recorded and you are publishing once again with previous name then previous recording will be overwrite by new one.

For view propose only:

you can connect multiple user with same stream name for view / listen purpose only. but you can publish stream data.

for metadata you can add same except the stream name event to base url will be remaining same. it will not become issue if Stream ID (Name) will be different.